# Why was `apt` made when we already have `apt-get`?

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, deb

In Debian >= 8, we now have `apt` as well as `apt-get`.  How does `apt` compare to `apt-get`, and why did the developers decide to create a new program?

A quote from the [Debian Administrator's Handbook](https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.apt-get.html):

> APT is a vast project, whose original plans included a graphical
>   interface. It is based on a library which contains the core
>   application, and apt-get is the first front end — command-line based —
>   which was developed within the project. apt is a second command-line
>   based front end provided by APT which overcomes some design mistakes
>   of apt-get.

What design mistakes are they talking about?

Comment: I don't believe, discussing the merits or lack thereof, of applications is suitable for this site, as the discussion is more about design than the technical "how-to"s nature of questions here

Comment: @MelBurslan Well, which SE would you suggest for a question like this? You could flag me, and see what a mod has to say...

Comment: I don't believe there is a SE section for these discussions. The atmosphere here is figuring out how to fix things, not really discussing the merits of OSes or applications. I think your best bet is finding a hard-core developer forum, especially one about *APT* or `apt-get`. I am not sure what else to say.

Comment: I'd have an easier time voting to reopen this question if it focused on the functional differences (i.e. title and 2nd sentence), and omitted the last sentence.

Comment: @JeffSchaller  I get where you are coming from, but if I got rid of that part of the question, it would make the accepted answer not make much sense -- and it really is a good answer.  Any ideas?

Comment: I suppose that since the question has an accepted answer, my opinion is the the title and 2nd sentence be adapted to the actual final question, to better reflect the answer.

Comment: @JeffSchaller, it's been a long time since this one got closed, but I think it is less opinion-based now.  I wanted to make sure it still matched the answer as well.

Comment: @Questionmark - I wasn't sure that anyone could answer the "why did developers decide to...?" question. Since the question has an accepted answer, is there a need to reopen it?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Actually, someone *could* answer the question, namely the developers. :-) And, as I recall, David kind of did, see my answer. I personally think it's fine to reopen the question. I don't really think it is opinion-based. There was a reason this new binary was created, as David briefly describes.

Comment: The Q has 3 reopen votes; I won't personally vote one way or the other. My concern about the "why" remains, as it would require the presence of the developer(s) here, or their comments -- as Faheem was able to gather. I don't think it's a good question to ask *in general* as it's hard to find primary evidence.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`apt` is mostly intended as a new binary with some of the commonly used features of both `apt-get` and `apt-cache` (with more to be added later, probably), and with a "simplified" interface. Most of `APT`'s available command line functionality is exposed via `apt-cache` and `apt-get`, but these commands aren't ideal from a user experience point of view. Since those two binaries were intended as test/example commands (originally by Jason Gunthorpe, I believe), and not for serious end-user usage.

The `apt` command is meant to be easier to use, and more "user-friendly". People often find it confusing that functionality is split between `apt-get` and `apt-cache` for instance.

See comments by Michael Vogt in his blog post:
[apt 1.0](https://mvogt.wordpress.com/2014/04/04/apt-1-0/).

I don't think it is particularly meant to be about overcoming design mistakes.

So, it's not intended as an `apt-get` replacement.

For more information, try asking the APT developers themselves. They are super-cool, but they don't hang out on Stack Exchange. Try `#debian-apt` on OFTC instead.

Comments from Michael Vogt on the said `#debian-apt` channel; I posted
the question link on the IRC channel.

> <mvo> faheem: "design mistakes" is a bit of a strong word - we are just
>   scared of changing anything in apt-get because it's used in a
>   gazillion scripts by now. "apt" lets us do that plus it's easier to
>   type and we can combine apt-get/apt-cache. so I think the answers are
>   all fine, the key part is really that apt is more convenient to
>   use/type.
>
> <￼mvo> faheem: [snip] the gist is that apt/apt-get/apt-cache all share
>   the same library and code, just some tweaks to the default.

Comment: Based on your quotes from Michael Vogt, I assume that you already asked them my question...?

Comment: @Questionmark No, I just posted the question on the IRC channel.

Answer (score 4):

From the man page:

```
DIFFERENCES TO APT-GET(8)
   The apt command is meant to be pleasant for end users and does not need to be 
   backward compatible like apt-get(8). Therefore some options are
   different:

   ·   The option DPkg::Progress-Fancy is enabled.

   ·   The option APT::Color is enabled.

   ·   A new list command is available similar to dpkg --list.

   ·   The option upgrade has --with-new-pkgs enabled by default.
```